# Stored Procedures under Source Control, best practice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, version-control, source-control

I am currently using Tortoise SVN to source control a .NET Web Application. What would be the best way to bring our SQL Server stored procedures into Source Control? I am currently using VS 2010 as my development environment and connecting to an off-premise SQL Server 2008 R2 database using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).

What I have been doing in the past is saving the procs to a .sql file and keeping this files under source control. I'm sure there must be a more efficient way than this? Is there an extension I can install on VS2010, SSDT or even SQL Server on the production machine?

Comment: If you're using the SSDT project type in Visual Studio, add that project to source control. That's it.

Comment: Please clarify your objective(s) -- are you just looking for versioning of the database objects, or are you trying to use this as a deployment platform as well?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146543/what-is-the-best-way-to-version-control-my-sql-server-stored-procedures

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are tools out there, such as [this from Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), but I have always found that best is to save as SQL files, perhaps even in a Database Project (SSDT?) in your solution.

Along with this, I suggest the following guidelines:

- Always assume the SVN version as the "current" / "latest"
- Ensure that every script you run has an appropriate "`if exists then drop`" at the start
- Remember to script your permissions, if any

You can initially create these SQL files by scripting directly from SSMS, and you can set SSMS to script all your "`drop`" and "`create`" as well as your permissions.

Comment: I was unaware of the database project type and have only just started exploring SSDT, but this looks promising. I've opted for this solution as there's no dependency on 3rd party tools and I can easily drop the .sql files into our current Source Control.

Comment: Also do not allow rights to devs on prod and those with rights only deploy from source control.

Comment: Be careful with "if exists them drop, (re)create with new definition" if changing tables/views that are referenced by other views/procs. I have hit circumstances where the output of such dependent views is corrupt (column type and contents moved but names not) due to a query plan being reused without recompile assuming the previous structure. A safer option is "if not exists create dummy" followed by "alter table/view/proc" as alter will follow sysdepends records to invalidate plans as needed and drop+create will not as drop wipes such records and create won't scan for dangling references.

Comment: The comment by @DavidSpillett is even more important if you have triggers in version control, because drop + create can fail even on deadlock, shouldn’t happen with create dummy + alter

Answer (score 4):

Saving the SQL files in source control provides control over the SQL files only. It doesn't control the changes of the actual database objects, nor it prevents simultaneous changes of the same database object by multiple users (and I guess you would like to have that under control, too). 
What we use is a 3rd party tool ([ApexSQL Version](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_version.aspx)), it integrates both with SSMS and VS, you can chose whether to work with a database version of the object, or with a Source Control version. If you're editing a database version, it's automatically checked out only to you, so no one else can edit it (it doesn't merge changes from different users). Only when you check it in again, others can modify it. And you can have your SC version different from the version of a live object (I use that when I leave for the day and plan to finish the edits and test it on the next)

Answer (score 3):

Use RedGate Source Control to hook it up to your source control.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

It will hook your SSMS directly to your source control repository and even allows for checking in static data.

Works like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Try [Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), highly recommended and free.

From the homepage:

> AnkhSVN is a Subversion Source Control Provider for Microsoft Visual Studio 2005, 2008, 2010 **and 2012**.
>
> AnkhSVN provides Apache™ Subversion® source code management support to all project types supported by Visual Studio and allows you to perform the most common version control operations directly from inside the Microsoft Visual Studio IDE.
>
> The Pending Changes dashboard gives you a unique insight in your development process and provides easy access to the source code and issue management features. The deep source code control (SCC) integration allows you to focus on developing, while AnkhSVN keeps track of all your changes and provides you the tools to effectively handle your specific needs.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried both RedGate and Visual Studio's database project  and I prefer the storing the database definition in the database project.
As soon as the database becomes part of the solution, you can use your preferred source control provider. Most have excellent Visual Studio integration.

With the SSDT tools you have the 'lastest version' of the database definition, allowing you to easily make schema comparisons and generate schema upgrade scripts.

That said, the schema is usually only a part of the equasion. In real life it turns out that databases allready have a lots of data. And my users tend to get rather disappointed when they loose it.

So as soon as I rolled out v1.0 the need arrises to maintain upgrade scripts. Sometimes these just contain schema changes, but  many times I need to create defaults based on the content of some other table, need to release a particular constraint until I seeded the data etc. Usually simply upgrading the schema does not quite cut it. My preference is to have these upgrade script in a separate folder in the database project too. These would usually look like 'upgrade from v1.0 to v1.1'.

My databases always have a reference table that tells me the current version number, so I can block incompatible upgrades. The first statement in my upgrade scripts check the current version and bail out if it's different from what's expected.

Another benefit from the database projects is to be able to deploy different sets of data based on the same schema. I have a different datasets for development,  the QA team, user acceptence test and for automated integration tests. Since a database project can have only 1 post-deploy script, the trick here is to make a new database project that references the 'master' project and to make the custom dataset part of the post deployment proces of that project.

These were my 2 cents, Whatever proces you come up, above all, it must fit you and your team and hopefully support you with most of the common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a tool myself.

It's available for free download -http://www.gitsql.net

I hope it helps other people who want to achieve the same end goal.

Here is an article which describes how to source control SQL Server. http://gitsql.net/documentation-04_SQL_Server_and_GIT

I've tried to make it as easy as possible. (3 screens)

- Connect to SQL Server
- Select objects
- Chose folder to export to /import from

I also - accidentally - added the feature of being able
   to selectively chose individual objects to import - or export. Which
   makes it much easy whilst developing.

I would usually make a change to a stored procedure and a table, and then export those two objects to a GIT directory.

Then i use Source Tree to visually see the changes and then commit them into bitbucket if i'm happy.

Comment: free download - but only for 20 objects.  This answer is just an advert for your product.

Answer (score 0):

My company has just developed this [new tool](http://servantt.com) (**free**) that helps you to easily **extract scripts** for SQL databases, can do **comparison**, can **launch WinMerge** for quickly comparing scripts to live database, and can also **synch differences** both updating the scripts or applying the changes to the database (except for tables, which would involve more complexity and more risks).

**Servantt is the WinMerge for comparing SQL Server Databases to Version-Controlled Scripts.**

It supports and encourages best-practices in software development:

- Keeping Database objects under version-control (*)
- Removing access rights from developers on production environments
- DBA review of changes in procedures/views for performance bottlenecks and naming standards
- Naming objects using fully qualified identifiers and bracketed delimiters (it fixes the CREATE PROCEDURE/VIEW/FUNCTION/etc scripts)

(*) Scripts are saved into a local folder that can be a working copy of Git, Subversion, TFS, Source Safe, or any other VCS.

Free Download: http://servantt.com

The professional version (which is still under development) will be a completely different beast - it's targeted at deployment automation (release management), for automating tasks such as updating IIS, updating Windows Services, etc.

Comment: This tool doesn't work.

Comment: @NeerajKumar there is a "contact us" address in the page where you can describe your problem. I'll be glad to help. There are more than a thousand active users, I assume it works in some sense :-)